# How to test for multiple possible outcomes with have_content?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm new to testing, so bear with me :)

I would like to test for random content on a page. For example, let's test the page for displaying the content either 'foo' or 'bar'.

Something like the below is what I'm trying to achieve

```
page.should (have_content('foo') || have_content('bar'))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: IMHO the title of your question is a bit misleading. It has nothing to do with statistics. Right? Call it "testing for complex condition" or whatever (I'm bad at making titles). Think about other people looking for an answer to your question.

Comment: Agreed. Hope the new title is sufficient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know any ready to use [Mather](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html) for you. But you can bake your own.

using [satisfy](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000440):

`page.should satisfy {|page| page.has_content?('foo') or page.has_content?('bar')}`

or [simple_matcher](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000441)

```
def have_foo_or_bar
  simple_matcher("check content has foo or bar") { |page| page.has_content?('foo') or page.has_content?('bar') }
end

describe page
  it "should have foo or bar" do
    page.should have_foo_or_bar
  end
end
```

**Edit:** `has_content` accepts regex, so you can check for `page.should have_content(/foo|bar/)`

Comment: Using satisfy worked. Couldn't get simple_matcher to work as it was spitting out NoMethodErrors. From my understanding, the method has been deprecated? Would have preferred using simple_matcher for the custom error message. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Right, the links I gave you are rather outdated. Sorry :( Don't know why Google shows it on top, should be updating it. :) Current version is 2.8 [RSpec Expectations 2.8](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations). The closest thing to simple_matcher is [define matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question but realized it's probably easier & more resilient to add an if statement to your spec.

```
it 'can complete my incredible form' do
  visit '/testing_path'
  #...dostuff...

  if object_im_testing.contains_my_condition?
    current_path.should eq('/special_condition_url')
  else
    current_path.should eq('/normal_condition_url')
  end
end
```

Hope this helps w/ another perspective. Simplest solution is usually the best.